# Grails - Cascading validation to specific subset of associations

Tags: validation, grails

Assuming I have got a domain class called `SomeClass` and this class has got some `hasMany` associations with some other classes, e.g. `AssociateOne`, `AssociateTwo`, and `AssociateThree`. All of these associates have a `belongsTo` which points to `SomeClass`.

If I now have an instance of `SomeClass` and calling `validate()` for this instance usually all associated instances are validated as well unless I use `validate(deepValidate: false)`.

I now wonder if there is a possibilty to exclude all `AssociateThree` instances from the cascaded validation, but validate only `AssociateOne` and `AssociateTwo` instances when calling `validate()` on a `SomeClass` instance?

Comment: The documentation talks about using `include` and `exclude` parameters for `validate`. I'd suggest you read the documentation instead of asking a question here. Hint: `myClass.validate(deepValidate: true, exclude: ['prop1', 'prop2'])`

Comment: Thanks for the hint, didn't find it here though: [http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/validate.html](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/validate.html)

Comment: I'd hate to think they actually removed that in later versions of Grails. Sorry, didn't know v3.x didn't have that in the documentation.